# jquery toggle did not work properly

Tags: jquery

```
function advanced_search()
{

$("#advanced_link").toggle( 
function(){
$('#advanced_link').text('Hide - Advanced Search');
$('.advanced_search').show();
},
function(){
$('#advanced_link').text('Show - Advanced Search');
$('.advanced_search').hide();

});
}
```

this code worked for me..but when i tried to use the css property like

```
function advanced_search()
{

$("#advanced_link").toggle( 
function(){
$('#advanced_link').text('Hide - Advanced Search');
$('.advanced_search').css('display','inline');
},
function(){
$('#advanced_link').text('Show - Advanced Search');
$('.advanced_search').css('display','none');

});
}
```

it did not work...is there any thing wrong in second code...??

Comment: which part did not work? the hide part or the show part or both?

Comment: ew. this code is smells.

Comment: @pradeep: Accept answers which are helpful to your questions, this way, more people will try to answer your questions.

Comment: $('.advanced_search').css('display','inline');

and 
$('.advanced_search').css('display','none');

did not work

Comment: heye there is a input field in the .advanced_search class thts it nothing else.

i have set the style of the advanced_search like
.advanced_search{
display:none;
}
in the css file..does this effect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shot in the dark**

Instead of inline, use block

```
$('.advanced_search').css('display','block');
```